# ArrrayList inside Hashmap in retrieving key values

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

```
private static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> loadValues = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
static ArrayList details = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I enter 2 set of values... say.. key:1 values: abc, c@c.com, 555 and key:2 values: xyz,x@z.com,765

i tried this.

```
System.out.println("Enter the User ID:");
        userID = in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        name = in.next();
        details.add(name);
        System.out.println("Enter your e-mail:");
        email = in.next();
        details.add(email);
        System.out.println("Enter your contact number:");
        contactNo = in.next();
       details.add(contactNo);
        loadValues.put(userID, details);
```

and used iterator to print...
When i try to print, it prints like...

```
1: abc, c@c.com, 555 ,xyz,x@z.com,765
 2:  abc, c@c.com, 555 ,xyz,x@z.com,765
```

But, i need to print,  `1: abc, c@c.com, 555  and 2: xyz,x@z.com,765`
what should i do?

Comment: Could you provide the code you use to print the values?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't create a new List for your two records. Since details is static, both records in your map point to the same List.

```
static List a = new ArrayList();
a.add(foo);
map.put(1, a);
a.add(bar);
map.put(2, a);
map.get(1) == map.get(2)
>> true
```

You need to do something like :

```
List a = fillList();
List b = fillList();
map.put(1, a);
map.put(2, b);
```

Where fillList represents creating new instance of List and filling it.

Comment: loadMap{System.out.println("Enter the User ID:"); userID = in.next(); System.out.println("Enter your name:"); name = in.next(); details.add(name); System.out.println("Enter your e-mail:"); email = in.next(); details.add(email); loadValues.put(userID, details); } display{ Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next(); System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());}

Comment: Danstahr: Yeah..Can you little brief on it?But i give the resultset values dynamically.In case I create instances for the list, it may increase as my record rows increases right?